# Check transform property from element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

In my css file i say

```
@media (min-width: 287px) {
    #footer-div
    {
        transform: translateY(93%);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 472px) {
    #footer-div
    {
        transform: translateY(89%);
    }
}
```

etc...
Now in javascript plain i want to get the value that applies. So in this case 93% or 89%.
something like :

```
var stylenow = document.getElementById("footer-div").style.transform...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? What would you expect it to be?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do with it? because it seems like you already know its going to be 93% and if its going to be dynamic why not set it via javascript in the first place?

Comment: you can try `Element.style.transform` but this will give you the whole CSS value

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DomMatrix/WebKitCSSMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix)

```js
var myElement = document.querySelector('.box');

function getTranslateY() {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(myElement);
  var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);
  console.log('translateY: ', `${matrix.m42}%`);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getTranslateY);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: teal;
  transform: translateY(92%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button type="button">get value</button>
```

Comment: [`DOMMatrix`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) is the standard name for this.